# Label X-Axis as Year in Correlogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I am trying to plot a correlogram of time series data but cannot label the X-Axis as years.

```
set.seed(1)
ts1 <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(42, a=5.717151, b=18.765000, mean=18.736, sd=16.31536)
ts <- ts(ts1, start = 1980, end = 2022, frequency = 1)

ggplot(NULL, aes(y = ts, x = seq_along(ts))) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1980,2022,3)) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Year') + ylab('Inflation Rate (in %)') + #ggtitle(expression("(a)\nsd = 1\n"~phi~"=.8")) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0, vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0.0), axis.title = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 14), plot.title = element_text(size = 14, margin = margin(t = 25, b = -20, l = 0, r = 0))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00)) + ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

This is what I have as [image: a plot]

**What I Want**

I want the X-Axis to be labeled as year starting from 1980 to 2022 with a convinient space inbetween. I tried using `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1980,2022,1))` but the lebel does not show up in the plot.

**Update**

I am thinking that `lubridate` package can help without writing to much functio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timeseries object into a dataframe then plot:

```
d <- data.frame(Y = as.matrix(ts), date = time(ts))

ggplot(d, aes(y = Y, x = date)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1980, 2022, 1))
```

(Note, I removed irrelevant aesthetic bits of code to the problem)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply that your `x` axis variable is running from 1 to 41 and your breaks don't fit into this limits. Hence, no breaks show up.

To fix that I would create a dataframe with a `date` column for your years and a column for your time series data.

```r
set.seed(1)
ts1 <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(42, a = 5.717151, b = 18.765000, mean = 18.736, sd = 16.31536)

library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  date = seq(1980, 2021, 1),
  ts = ts1
)

ggplot(dat, aes(y = ts, x = date)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1980, 2021, 1)) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") +
  geom_point(color = "#101820FF") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Inflation Rate (in %)") +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(
      size = 10, angle = 0, vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0.0
    ),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 10
    ),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 14
    ),
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 14, margin = margin(t = 25, b = -20, l = 0, r = 0)
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

[image]